# Required field in custom component showing required when filled

Tags: antd

I'm trying to get my custom input component to function with the standard `required` checks. In my playground code I put these lines:

```
<Form.Item label='as' name='ass' rules={[{required: true, message: 'basdasd'}]}>
<Input placeholder="asd" />
</Form.Item>
```

This code will show a require message when you click submit and clear the message when you type something. Just like the example for dynamic rules in the documentation.

Now I also have this code:

```
<Form.Item rules={[{ required: true, message: 'basdasaaasd' }]} id='micp_form_item_fld_password' name='b'>
<MicpTextField strCode='fld_password' oOriginalProps={{ value: strPassword, onChange: funcSetField, size: 'small' }} />
</Form.Item>
```

This will also show the field as `required` when you click submit which putting a value in the field. However when you type something the field will still be seen as empty, well at least the required check fails. I'm thinking I either need to do something with `onChange`, or pass some more original values. In the custom component, as child you have an `Input`.

The `funcSetField` code is:

```
const funcSetField = e => {
if (e.target.id === 'micp_fld_email') {
setFldEmail(e.target.value);
} else {
setFldPassword(e.target.value);
}
};
```

However there is no difference when I remove the this function, execept that you then can't type something in the input field.

Any advice?

Comment: I think I found a direction for the solution. I see my id is not the same as the working one. It seems that's generated by the form and form.item properties. I'll dig into that, also I'll try the `customized form control component`. I think I missed some must have options.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue lay in not having triggers for onChange etc. Following the customized for control from the manual helped me solve this